# Positioning Gtk Widgets in Window

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I'm currently learning PyGObject in order to create a small Gtk application, and I've become a bit stuck in laying out the Gtk Widgets correctly in the application window. The desired layout I am trying to achieve is below:

```
+-------+
| Label |
+-------+---+
| Combo Box |
+-----------+--------+
| Label     | Button |
+-----------+--------+
| Button             |  |
+--------------------+   > Dialog window of buttons of dynamic length
| Button             |  |
+--------------------+  |
| Button             |  |
+--------------------+  |
...
```

I have read the documentation on layout containers here, https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html, but I'm having difficulty finding how I can set the properties of the Gtk Grid to resemble the above layout. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction here. Should I be using a Gtk Grid for this, or some other layout? Do I need to write up an XML file to set this layout, or is it possible to do something like this in the code?

Comment: There are a lot of information and examples about Layout Containers in the official documentation here https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html

Comment: I was first trying to set this layout using a single Gtk Grid, but now I'm thinking that I should instead use a separate Gtk Box for each row above the dialog window. Would this be the correct way to represent this? Specifically the issue I am having is that the Grid cells stretch depending on the largest cell when I want each to be a distinct size and to align to the left. I tried setting the homogeneous_row and homogeneous_column to False, but I'm unsure how I can then set individual cell dimensions.

Comment: Yes, I think multiple Gtk.Box are easier for this case. Anyway on gtk you do not set individual cell dimensions, the dimensions are calculated as needed by the widgets